# Sqlite, DB clients & BLOB's: Practical DB Use

Tags: database, client, sqlite

I'm looking for a client that helps me to make practical use of a DB.  I'm looking at SQLite since it's simple, embedded (stored in a file rather than accessed via a server) and has a shell interface that I can use to script in data.  The plan is to insert mp3's as BLOBs ("binary large objects"); and I understand there are two ways to do this: either put the mp3 itself in the DB, or merely include a reference to the mp3 file.  Each record will also include transcripts/notes/tags

What kind of client can I use to access this DB as a *user*?  I'd like to be able to click on the mp3 and listen to it, then add text data in the other fields, and finally search on text in the DB.  LibreOffice Base is a nice client that allows me to define forms, but I'm not clear if simple access to the mp3 is possible.  Are there other options?

Comment: This would be a matter of opinion. You would probably be able to cobble together something with LibreOffice. However, the way I would do it is to access the mp3 collection through (1) a browser, accessing (2) a (small) local web server that serves up  (3) web pages generated by python or perl scripts that (4) access the DB.  This has the advantage that the solution is clean, portable and modular.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't put the actual mp3 files into the SQLite database. Either you double the amount of storage needed, or you render the mp3 files inaccessible by other means.

Comment: @Jos - thanks for your help, as always.  I had come to the same conclusion as you regarding keeping the mp3s outside of the DB, though I wasn't clear if putting them in might simplify direct access.  My difficulty regarding your suggestion of a web server/python scripts is that while I know bash scripting, all of the rest will be another hurdle (or two) to jump.  (I am, for example, using AWK to take text files and create insert statements.)  I will learn Python, just ... I do have a pressing need for this project.